# Is the clothing listed in your equipment intended to be the clothes you're wearing or extra clothes that you've packed?

Tags: dnd-5e, equipment, encumbrance

Every background provides you with clothes appropriate for your character.  Because it's listed as "equipment" and because the Adventuring Gear table provides weights for several types of clothing [PHB pg. 150], it's reasonable to conclude that this mass must be accounted for when ensuring you remain under your carrying capacity, which is 15 lbs times your strength score [PHB pg. 176].  That's simple enough, and the 15 x STR limit is high enough to be effectively irrelevant unless you're trying to haul away a dragon's hoard.

However, if you're playing with the encumbrance variant [also PHB pg. 176], things can get more problematic.  In that scenario, there's a movement penalty imposed for carrying more than 5 x STR, and quite severe penalties for carrying more than 10 x STR.  For this reason, I prefer my characters to regularly carry no more than 10 x STR, and then to configure their gear in such a way that they can drop their pack to leave themselves with a "combat load" (of weapons, armor, precious items, etc.) that's less than 5 x STR.

However, I find myself pushing the limits when I have a character with average-to-low strength (say 8 or 10) and medium armor (usually 20-45 lbs).  In this scenario, every pound matters, so I need to know: Is the clothing in a character's equipment actually a *change* of clothes, able to be stored in their pack and dropped during combat?  Or is it added mass that they're wearing (under or over their armor) into battle?

Naked adventurers need not apply.  (Bards should put their clothes back on.  And barbarians . . . well, you do you.)

---

After further consideration, I've noted that the various sets of clothing in the Adventuring Gear table weigh from 3 to 6 pounds.  I believe this is significantly more than a single day's set of modern clothing weighs, which would support the idea of this being *extra* clothing, but I have no actual data on the typical mass of modern or medieval clothing to back this up.

Comment: The question in the title doesn't seem to match the question in the text. From the text it seems you more interested in whether clothing needs to be worn under/along with armor. Is this correct?

Comment: No, not exactly.  The question is whether the clothes in your equipment are extra clothes you keep in your pack or if they're clothes that you wear on your body (with your armor) during a normal adventuring day.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

#### You are carrying the clothes you are wearing.

This is not spelled out explicitly in the PHB or DMG, but I think this is common sense. Anything on your person that is not on you when you are totally naked contributes to the weight you are carrying.

If I weigh myself naked, I am going to weigh less than when I weigh myself when I put on my jeans, shirt, belt, and boots, and you said it yourself, "Naked adventurers need not apply".

You do not have a set of weightless default clothes (well, you do, your *birthday suit*). You have clothes made of materials that have mass and contribute to your carried weight.

But do you have to wear your clothes *with* your armor? That’s entirely up to you, and *up to your DM to decide if the NPCs think you look ridiculous*. Full plate armor? Probably don’t need the clothes. Breastplate? Better at least put some pants on.

The variant encumbrance rules are *by design* supposed to make you worry about every pound. Thinking about how your selection of armor relates to your normal clothes is exactly the kind of decision the variant encumbrance rules are trying to force. That you have this problem means that these variant rules have achieved their purpose, and if you find that less fun, talk to your DM about some sort of compromise or houserule, or if the variant rule is right for you and your table at all.

Just to give an idea of how much clothes actually weigh, I weighed myself with and without my work clothes.

Full work clothes:

[image]

Just my skivvies:

[image]

A difference of 7.6 pounds. A range of 3-6 pounds for the starting clothes is probably because adventurers can’t afford a decent pair of boots just starting out - my boots alone are nearly 5 pounds.

Comment: Some spells (particularly those that deal with fire like good ol' [Fireball](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/fireball)) refer to things that "aren't worn or carried." The fact that both words are used would seem to indicate that there is some sort of relevant distinction between the two, though I do agree that, in practice, the two are probably interchangeable much of the time.

Comment: I think that's more of a protection against abuse of the general language of "carry", and not something that defines a distinction between worn and carried.

Comment: @Rykara Do we have examples of things that interact differently with items that are worn versus carried? Otherwise, "worn or carried" sounds like it's just being maximally inclusive.

Comment: I will mention, I weighed myself both wearing and carrying my work clothes and I weighed the same.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov the difference, by OP's question, is that carried weight can be dropped in combat while worn weight cannot.

Comment: @smbailey I understand that. The calculus of my answer is exceedingly simple. Are you wearing your clothes? Count it against your weight. Are your clothes lying on the ground? Don’t count it against your weight.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov Oh I agree and you've had my upvote, but I think since OP seems concerned about weight specifically in combat the distinction between worn and carried is important here. Not whether the weight is different, but whether the clothing needs to be worn in combat seems important to OP's question.

Comment: @Mark Possibly Black Pudding (creature) and shields: "In addition, nonmagical armor worn by the target is partly dissolved and takes a permanent and cumulative -1 penalty to the AC it offers." Also True Polymorph says "The target's gear melds into the new form. The creature can't activate, use, wield, or otherwise benefit from any of its equipment." Armor is technically listed as a separate thing from "equipment" in the rules so one could argue that, say, a gorilla could still wear and benefit from armor because armor is not equipment and the spell doesn't say "can't wear," only "can't wield."

Comment: **Historical Note:** In Dungeons and Dragons Third Edition, worn clothing explicitly didn't count against carrying capacity, but worn armour did. I always assumed this was to prevent munchkins from going naked.

Comment: @Mark Wells one distinction is that something carried could be be disarmed or pickpocketed or otherwise removed from your person; something worn probably couldn't.

Comment: @Rykara To be entirely transparent, I can’t imagine a player insisting to the DM that the black pudding didn’t damage armor the player was (quite oddly) holding in hand rather than wearing.

Comment: @smbailey: On the other hand, in real life, another distinction is that clothing (or armor) is *much* easier to carry if you're wearing it than if you're not, because the weight is distributed evenly over your body. For example, it's a lot easier to wear a full suit of plate armor and carry a bathrobe than it is to wear the bathrobe and carry the suit of armor. (Just try it if you don't believe me. Or look up some videos online of people doing acrobatics while wearing armor.) So, from a realism / game balance viewpoint, it would make perfect sense for worn items to cause less encumbrance.

Comment: It is probably best to note that one is *not* wearing “just” plates of metal over their naked bodies if they are wearing “just” full-plate armor: full-plate armor consists of heavy padding, covered by chain, with plates on top of *that*. The padding might not be super-comfortable to wear directly against skin, but it shouldn’t be *bad* —while chain or plate directly on skin would cause substantial pinching, chafing, and cutting, even with regular clothes between (which is why the padding is part of the package deal).

Comment: @KRyan Or, as Cerebus said to Red Sophia, "They'd probably heal if you'd stop wearing that chainmail bikini."

Comment: I’ve gained 20 pounds since I wrote this answer >.<

Answer (score 9):

## The extra clothing is worn separately from armor

The descriptions of the armor in the [equipment section](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/equipment#ArmorandShields) include information like:

> ***Padded.*** Padded armor consists of quilted layers of cloth and batting.
> ...
> ***Chain Shirt.*** Made of interlocking metal rings, a chain shirt is worn between layers of clothing or leather. This armor offers modest protection to the wearer's upper body and allows the sound of the rings rubbing against one another to be muffled by outer layers.
> ...
> ***Chain Mail.*** Made of interlocking metal rings, chain mail includes a layer of quilted fabric worn underneath the mail to prevent chafing and to cushion the impact of blows. The suit includes gauntlets.

While not explicitly stated in the rulebook, it seems like any set of armor donned includes everything necessary to wear said armor (such as underclothing, padding, etc.) included in its weight.

The clothing provided by the character's background is "civilian clothes" to be worn when not wearing armor. This clothing does have its own weight, but it can be considered **weight carried in your pack** that can be dropped when entering into combat, unless you are purposefully wearing it.

**Naked adventurers need not apply**

I would note that classes that do not wear armor, such as barbarians, monks, or some spellcasters, should be assumed to be wearing *something*, so in their case they would most likely be wearing the clothing from their background or something of similar weight.

Comment: I don't think "The clothing provided by the character's background is "civilian clothes" to be worn when not wearing armor." - specifically because most of the armors, especially for heavy armor, aren't things you'd just wear on top of bare skin. For example, "Half plate consists of shaped metal plates that cover most of the wearer's body." The padding of chain mail is necessary to "prevent chafing and to cushion the impact of blows", but that doesn't necessarily mean it takes the place of regular clothing - it just means that regular clothes don't do enough to cushion the blows.

Comment: @V2Blast I'm not asserting that you wear the armor on bare skin, but that purchasing the armor includes anything you need to effectively wear the armor. Historically most heavy armor was worn over a gambeson, which is basically the "padded armor" from the light armor section. The argument in my answer is that when you purchase and wear armor it includes all pieces of that armor, including padding (gambeson), leather or woolen pants, boots, etc. All included in the purchase price and weight of the armor, and worn _instead_ of common clothes not _on top of_.

Comment: Does a breastplate come with boots and pants? (Probably totally up to the DM).

Comment: @ThomasMarkov Agreed that it's up to the DM, but I would still personally say that the 400gp cost of the breastplate includes whatever combat-ready lightweight leggings and footwear you wear along with it, so it'd just weigh 20 pounds to wear the whole outfit, not 20 pounds plus the weight of your everyday clothing.